# How to assign 32 bit decimal number to the buffer in javascript so that buffer.isbuffer should return true if it contains decimal32

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, buffer

If I assign decimal32 to the buffer,it throws stream buffer underflow error.

```
      const bufferVar =  new Buffer(0.0000001*Math.pow(10, 101));

       x.properties.set('key1', bufferVar );
```

Comment: I am just assigning the buffer value which contains decimal32 to the map key

Comment: can you paste your error as well?

Comment: What platform and versions of node?

Comment: Windows 10 and Node v6